# ImageButton and Button in FrameLayout won't change z-index

Tags: android, android-layout

When you switch the order of the elements, place `Button` after `ImageButton`,  the z-index is not affected. I tried with other types of Views and they are positioned correctly on top of one another depending on their order in the parent `FrameLayout`.
I tried programmatically with View.bringToFront() without success.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Suzi"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: whats the point of placing two buttons in a `FrameLayout`?

Comment: The buttons don't have an ID, how do you call bringToFront()? Post the code

Comment: The point is to have one Button placed aside, with some offset, but on top of the other.

Comment: Where I tried bringToFront() they have ID, the point here is I think they should change stack position when changed order in the Frame

Comment: Post the code, without it we can help you ... maybe you used bringToFront() in the wrong way or something else, now we can only trust in your word

Comment: Just tried findViewById(R.id.b2).bringToFront(); in the sample. Doesn't work. And when I change Buttons to TextView for example, it does.

Comment: The issue is 100% reproduced in the sample, I don't see any need to post the snippet from the project

Comment: Weirdly, it works with two Buttons and two ImageButtons, but not with Button and ImageButton

Comment: The main thing that should. Tested on an emulator and the real device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue: it is reproduced for me on Lollipop+ devices and isn't reproduced on pre-Lollipop.
Could you please check this?

If it is exactly the case, then the solution might be to use `android:translationZ` attribute (which is available since Lollipop)

Something like:

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Suzi"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:translationZ="1dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:translationZ="2dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

And that fact that translationZ isn't available on pre-Lollipop would not matter (and attribute would be ignored), as there is no such issue.

Hope it helps